# How to decide and apply priorties in /etc/rc0.d

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, init.d

I have script "backup-before-shutdown" which should be running before shutdown ! So I have created link to it in "/etc/rc0.d"
I just want to know should I add some priorities (K,S, or some numbers) or just keeping this link in that directory will do (as its production I can't do testing ) 
If I have to add priorities how to decide it as well as how to apply it ? Is that renaming file to K35backup-before-shutdown is sufficient ?

$ ll

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Nov 16 10:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 100 root root 4096 Nov  6 16:23 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   34 Nov 16 10:06 backup-before-shutdown -> /etc/init.d/backup-before-shutdown*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Feb 16  2015 K08tomcat7 -> ../init.d/tomcat7*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Apr 17  2015 K09apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   29 Sep 27  2014 K10unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   26 Sep 27  2014 K15landscape-client -> ../init.d/landscape-client*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   15 Sep 27  2014 K20rsync -> ../init.d/rsync*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   24 Sep 27  2014 K20screen-cleanup -> ../init.d/screen-cleanup*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   23 Sep 27  2014 K38open-vm-tools -> ../init.d/open-vm-tools*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  351 Mar 13  2014 README
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Sep 27  2014 S20sendsigs -> ../init.d/sendsigs*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Sep 27  2014 S30urandom -> ../init.d/urandom*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   22 Sep 27  2014 S31umountnfs.sh -> ../init.d/umountnfs.sh*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Sep 27  2014 S40umountfs -> ../init.d/umountfs*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   26 Sep 27  2014 S59cryptdisks-early -> ../init.d/cryptdisks-early*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   20 Sep 27  2014 S60umountroot -> ../init.d/umountroot*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   16 Sep 27  2014 S90reboot -> ../init.d/reboot*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read `man update-rc.d`. There is a system to the names, and you will have a happier life if you learn it, rather than figuring out your own. Also read `man run-parts`.

From `man update-rc.d`:

```
DESCRIPTION

       update-rc.d  updates   the   System   V   style   init   script   links
       /etc/rcrunlevel.d/NNname  whose  target is the script /etc/init.d/name.
       These links are run  by  init  when  it  changes  runlevels;  they  are
       generally  used  to  start  and  stop  system services such as daemons.
       runlevel  is  one  of  the  runlevels  supported   by   init,   namely,
       0123456789S,  and  NN  is the two-digit sequence number that determines
       where in the sequence init will run the scripts.

       This manpage documents only the usage  and  behaviour  of  update-rc.d.
       For  a discussion of the System V style init script arrangements please
       see init(8) and the Debian Policy Manual.
```